# Info WIndow with Map for the Clicked Marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on Google Map v3.
I need to display Map in infowindow on click of route marker.
Currently, my code displays adrress of the corresponding marker.
[image: Attched image is the example which I am trying to achive]
In the attached image, on click of Marker "B", small Map is opened with marker "B" centered.

Please let me know if anyone have any inputs.

Thanks,
Sharath

```
Below is my code snippet....
waypoints array contains the 2 points 2 display (origin and destination)
// Code starts from here...
var origin = waypoints[0];
var destination = waypoints[1];

var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25, 133),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapOptions);
var directions = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
directions.route({
                    origin: origin,
                    destination: destination,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                    unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.METRIC
                }, function(result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById     ("drivingDirections"));
                        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I have just created Direction Service and provided origin, destination.
I have not tried anything specific to get the Map in InfoWindow.
Below is my code,

    this.directions = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    this.directions.route({
                        origin: originPlace,
                        destination: destinationPlace,
                         travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                        unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.METRIC
                    }

Comment: Please provide your code so far, or even better, a jsFiddle.

Comment: I have updated my post with code...

Comment: Hi,
Does any one have any inputs, or is this something impossible in google map V3.